# I can't connect to WIFI but I can connect to hotspot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-11, wifi-configuration

My Problem is, that I can't connect to wifi in windows 11. I bough a new PC and apparently it has network issues. I can connect to my phone hotspot but I can't connect to my Wifi.
I'm sure my Wifi works, I tried it with my old pc.
I tried uninstalling network adapters, updating network adapters, restarted the pc several times, shut it down and booted up and I installed every Windows update, but somehow it still shows the message "unable to connect to this network". It's just weird that hotspot works. I just don't know what to do anymore, couldn't find anything on google either. I'd be happy if someone could help.

Comment: Your newer wifi maybe only has a higher speed band that your existing router does not have? Just a thought.

Comment: This ^^^^ or some old or not recommended settings in the router - your phone is OK with it but your brand new WiFi device, drivers and OS may not be - so check the WiFi encryption settings and make sure 1. WPA2-AES or newer, never TKIP that has been deprecated many years ago and 2. No WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, 3. Some other settings may need tweaks too.

Comment: @YeagerCS - can you answer the questions please